# Visit Canada from Dubai with a valid B1/B2 visa on a Pakistani passport

Tags: visas, canada, b1-b2-visas, eta

I am national of Pakistan and residing in Dubai for last 4.5 years. I have a valid US B1/B2 visa. I have travelled to th3 US multiple times. Do I need a visa or an eTA to travel to Canada for 15-20 days?

Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

You need a Canadian visa.  See [Do I need a visa to visit Canada?](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/helpcentre/answer.asp?qnum=416&top=16)

This will lead you to a tool that will tell you that you [you need a visa](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/visit/visas-result.asp?q2=no&country=PK&result=1).

Permanent residents of the US are exempted from the requirement to hold a Canadian visa, but this exemption does not apply to those who hold US visas.